# renaming key of json file

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I can change the value of key, but how can I rename json key by creating of function

```
    button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        var i = 0;
        i++;
        var name = "Jason " + i;
        var surname = "Carl " + i;
        writeJson(i, name, surname);
    });

    function writeJson(id, name, surname){
        var array = {
        id: {
            "name": name,
            "surname": surname
            }
        };
    }
```

in array id is not changing and i is not increasing

Comment: In that code, every time you click, i is set to 0 and then increased to 1. Therefore it is always going to be 1. You need to move the var i = 0; outside the click event

Answer (score 2):

Declare your `i` variable outside of your event listener callback.

The way it is now, you are resetting it every time you click the button.

```
var i = 0; // this is in the parent scope

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    i++;
    var name = "Jason " + i;
    var surname = "Carl " + i;
    writeJson(i, name, surname);
});

function writeJson(id, name, surname){
    var array = {
    id: {
        "name": name,
        "surname": surname
        }
    };
}
```

```js
var i = 0; // this is in the parent scope

button.addEventListener("click", function(){
    i++;
    console.log('i: ' + i)
});
```

```html
<button id="button">increment i</button>
```

Comment: I understood my mistake, thank you. But there is one problem. Why id is not changing ?

Comment: If your code looks like the above it should be incrementing with each click of the button. please see the snippet just added.

Answer (score 0):

First of all :

- You are calling `array` a variable which is of type `object`.
- You are using `id` as a key and as a parameter of your function which is somehow confusing due to (1) I assume you are new programmer.

If what you meant is to have the id as a key of the object called array:

```js
    var i = 0;
    var button = document.getElementById('test');
    button.addEventListener("click", function(){
        i++;
        var name = "Jason " + i;
        var surname = "Carl " + i;
        writeJson(i, name, surname);
    });

    function writeJson(id, name, surname){
        var array = {
          [id]: {
            "name": name,
            "surname": surname
            }
        };
        alert(JSON.stringify(array, null, 2));
    }
```

```html
<button type="button" id="test">Create new</button>
```